# structure of selfnodes changes when creating an xml file from another

Tags: c#, xml, clonenode

while creating an xml file from another one by cloning nodes from source to target file in c#, the structure of empty nodes like `<noeud></noeud>` becomes `<noeud/>`

i've tried this :

```
 if (nodeSource.InnerText.Equals(""))
     XmlNode nodeDestination = NodeSource.CloneNode(false);
```

is there any method to keep the same structure .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The format `<element/>` is frequently called a self-closing element.  It's 100% valid, and the preferred storage method.  If you **really** care (why?) re-writing to expanded format (`<element></element>`), you can look at writing your own XmlTextWriter.  This article will be helpful for you.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/nareshjoshi/archive/2009/01/15/how-to-force-non-self-closing-tags-for-empty-nodes-when-using-xslcompiledtransform-class.aspx

Comment: Okey @WilliamWalseth i'll try it , Thanks a lot :)